# React is not binding function call despite warnings to the contrary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component which needs to run a check in a `setTimeout()` call. The following is my method call

```
componentDidUpdate: function () {
    // Despite console warnings, React does *not* do this.
    var boundCheck = this.checkYourself.bind(this);
    if (!this.timeoutId) {
        this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
            boundCheck();
        }, UPDATE_CHECK_INTERVAL);
    }
},
```

This will produce the following warning on the console:

> bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.

However, if I change the method to the following:

```
componentDidUpdate: function () {
    if (!this.timeoutId) {
        this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
            this.checkYourself();
        }, UPDATE_CHECK_INTERVAL);
    }
},
```

I get an exception because `this` refers to `window`. Is there a way to do this which will make React happy?

Comment: Thanks, but saving `this` to a variable and using it inside of `setTimeout()` is a hacky way to do the same thing as `bind`. I'd rather try to do it "the right way" if React supports it, and it looks like it does!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind the function in the `setTimeout`:

```
componentDidUpdate: function () {
  if (!this.timeoutId) {
    this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
      this.checkYourself();
    }.bind(this), UPDATE_CHECK_INTERVAL);
  }
},
```

`this.checkYourself()` should now call the component as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.4, React auto bind all method you create in createClass and bind it to correct context, you just need to declare a method in createclass and call `setTimeout(this.method, 1000)` directly.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use arrow function to achieve this:

```
this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    this.checkYourself();
}, UPDATE_CHECK_INTERVAL);
```

Tested with react `v0.14.6`